# Connection refused error with solana-test-validator up and running in a separate pan (helloworld example)

Tags: solana

I am sure this must be a simple thing but it has happened on two different ubuntu instances where I tried to run the example-helloworld app. I am sure there is something I am doing wrong.

I am using Ubuntu to try and get the example-helloworld up and running.

I have followed the steps to build and deploy the app, which has all worked fine in a terminal pane. I have also started a "solana-test-validator" in a separate terminal pane, together with "solana logs" in a third pane.

I have also ensured I have solana's web3.js installed. When I run the command "npm start" in the first pane I get the following error show below. The solana-test-validator process seems to get killed when I run "npm start". Is there a obvious fix for this, to stop it getting killed?

---

```sh
FetchError: request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8899
at ClientRequest. (/root/example-helloworld/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
```

Comment: What version of Solana is installed? Did you build the Rust or C program first? How are you configured? `solana config get` will show you.

Answer (score 0):

As listed in [this ticket](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/issues/392), it seems that reverting to npm 16 may fix the issue. It solved it for me running on macOS.